# Render list-item (li) from an xTemplate inside a ul container in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

In an Extjs dataview, my itemTpl is an XTemplate for list items. How can I wrap my template output in a `<ul></ul>` tag so the list displays appropriately?

My current template:

```
Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
        '<tpl for".">',
            '<li class="faq-item">{title}',
            '<p class="content" style="">{content}</p>',
            '</li>',
        '</tpl>'
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer is to set the `autoEl` on the dataview.

```
xtype: 'dataview',
autoEl: {
    tag: 'ul'
},
...
```

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.view.View-cfg-autoEl

Answer (score 0):

And why don't you just put the `<ul>` element in the template?

```
Ext.create(
    'Ext.XTemplate',
    '<ul>',
        '<tpl for".">',
            '<li class="faq-item">{title}',
                '<p class="content" style="">{content}</p>',
            '</li>',
        '</tpl>',
    '</ul>'
);
```

Comment: when I tried this, it wrapped every single li element in a unique ul tag

Comment: Oh, you're right, you said it was for an `itemTpl`. But now I'm surprised that your for loop is working.